# Google Charts- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, charts, google-visualization, trendline

I'm using Google Charts and I'm trying to display trend lines on a table.  Only the first row of the table actually displays trend lines. I also get an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined error message. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's a screenshot of the error I get:[image: Google charts error message]

Here's My code:

```
     var dataFororange = [];
     var dataForred=[];
     var dataForblue=[];

    function calling(plot_data, color, row_num){
    if (color==1)
        dataFororange[row_num]=plot_data;        
    if (color==2) 
        dataForred[row_num]=plot_data;
    if (color==3) 
        dataForblue[row_num]=plot_data;
    }

    window.onload = function(e){ 
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(onChartLoad);
    }

    function onChartLoad() { 
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        drawOrangeColor(dataFororange[i], i);
        drawRedColor(dataForred[i], i);
        drawBlueColor(dataForblue[i], i);
    }   
    }

    function drawOrangeColor(amount, counter) {

    var dataA = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataA.addColumn('new Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, 
    Milliseconds)', 'X');
    dataA.addColumn('number', 'price');

    for(var i= 0; i<amount.X.length; i++){
        var date_string = amount.X[i];
        var year=date_string.slice(6,10);
        var month=date_string.slice(3,5);
        var day=date_string.slice(0,2);
        var dataY = amount.Y[i];
        dataA.addRows([[new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, 
    parseInt(day)), dataY]]);
    }
    var optionA = {
        legend: 'none',
        vAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                 gridlineColor: 'none',
                 textPosition: 'none' },
        hAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                gridlineColor: 'none',
                textPosition: 'none' },
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        colors:['#ff8800']
    };
    var pos = "A_chart"+counter;
    var selected = document.getElementById(pos);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(selected);
    chart.draw(dataA, optionA);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////
    function drawRedColor(amount, counter) {
    var dataB = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataB.addColumn('date', 'X');
    dataB.addColumn('number', 'price');
    for(var i= 0; i<amount.X.length; i++){
        var date_string = amount.X[i];
        var year=date_string.slice(6,10);
        var month=date_string.slice(3,5);
        var day=date_string.slice(0,2);
        var dataY = amount.Y[i];
        dataB.addRows([[new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, 
    parseInt(day)), dataY]]);
    }
    var optionB = {
        legend: 'none',
        vAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                 gridlineColor: 'none',
                 textPosition: 'none' },
        hAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                gridlineColor: 'none',
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                textPosition: 'none' },
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        colors:['red']
    };
    var pos = "B_chart"+counter;
    var selected = document.getElementById(pos);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(selected);
    chart.draw(dataB, optionB);
    }
    ///////////
    function drawBlueColor(amount, counter) {
    var dataC = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataC.addColumn('date', 'X');
    dataC.addColumn('number', 'price');
    for(var i= 0; i<amount.X.length; i++){
        var date_string = amount.X[i];
        var year=date_string.slice(6,10);
        var month=date_string.slice(3,5);
        var day=date_string.slice(0,2);
        var dataY = amount.Y[i];
        dataC.addRows([[new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, 
    parseInt(day)), dataY]]);
    }
    var optionC = {
        legend: 'none',
        vAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                 gridlineColor: 'none',
                 textPosition: 'none' },
        hAxis: { baselineColor: 'none',
                gridlineColor: 'none',
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                textPosition: 'none' },
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        colors:['blue']
    };
    var pos = "C_chart"+counter;
    var selected = document.getElementById(pos);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(selected);
    chart.draw(dataC, optionC);
    }

    function onUKChartLoad() {    
    drawOrangeColor(test_data);
    drawRedColor(test_data);
    drawBlueColor(test_data);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

On line 33 of your code, you are trying to get the property 'X' of an object. I'm not sure what X is supposed to be in this case, but you can try changing

```
amount.X.length
```

to

```
amount.length
```

to iterate through your array. Keep in mind, amount is being passed in as an argument in your function, so if you don't have a property 'X' when you call the function, it will be undefined.